# using credentials to Test-Path isn't working

Tags: powershell, credentials

I'm writing a script to check that our backup succeeded.  Unfortunately, the backup is in a different location/login.  The script is scheduled to run without user intervention, like the other ones do.  I'm adding in credential info that is saved, but the -Credential option isn't working.  It's still asking me to enter the login info in a popup login window, even with the -credential option I'm using.  Do you see an issue with the following?  I know the secure login works with another script so I don't think there's a problem with it's creation.  I think the problem is in using the credentials with Test-Path. From what I can see, I think I'm doing it correctly, according to this link, although they aren't using a stored credential like I am: [test-path with cred](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/58a86256-f9be-4042-93a6-e8339132e20b/testpaths-credential-parameter-is-it-ever-used?forum=winserverpowershell)

```
function GetSecureLogin (){
#this function will obtain secure login
   $TISusername = "username/here"
   #read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\filename.txt
   #Note: when you save password for re-use as above, programs that use it later must be using same login as had when saved password: ie. Script_Guru
   $TISpassword = get-content  C:\Scripts\filename.txt | convertto-securestring #may not need to re-convert to secure string since stored secure string
   $global:cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $TISusername, $TISpassword

}

Function CheckBackedUp($file, $destinationFolder)
{

    #get filename without folder
    $filename = $file.substring($file.lastindexofany("\") +1 ,$file.length - ($file.lastindexofany("\")+1)) 

    #$destinationFolder = split-path($file)
    #get date and append to fileNameWithoutExt
    #$ext = Get-Date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d" 
    $ext = "2014-06-11"
    $newFileName = $destinationFolder+"\"+$ext+"*"+$filename
    #look for file
    if(Test-Path "$newFileName" -Credential $global:cred) #this isn't working
    {
       Write-Host "$newFileName exists"
    }
    else
    {
        $temp = "$newFileName doesn't exist. "
        Write-Host "$temp "
        $global:resultMessage += $temp

    }

    #return failure message if don't find file with signature that contains $ext

} #CheckBackedUp

####start here
...
$global:cred = ""
GetSecureLogin

$global:resultMessage = ""

#loop through files, checking if we backed each one up
$i=0
try{
for ($i = $fileArray.GetLowerBound(0); $i -le $fileArray.GetUpperBound(0); $i++) { 
        $tempSource =  $fileArray[$i]
        #see if files were correctly backed up
        CheckBackedUp $tempSource $TisToLocation
}
...
```

****Update 6/27/2014****
When I tried using the following in place of the Test-Path if statement above

```
invoke-command -computername "usa02xxnas1.na.xxx.net" -credential $globalcred -scriptblock{Test-Path "$newFileName"}
```

I got this error message, which I don't understand how to fix:

```
[usa02xxxnas1.na.xxx.net] Connecting to remote server usa02xxnas1.na.xxx.net failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error 
with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.  
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (usa02xxnas1.na.xxx.net:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AuthenticationFailed,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: I was looking at this link for more info also: <http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx>  I noticed it says "This parameter is not supported by any providers installed with Windows PowerShell."  Does that refer to Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: It's not the host OS that's lacking the support, it's the `PSProvider` itself. IOW, the `-Credential` parameter exists, but it doesn't work in all cases. See [this discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/58a86256-f9be-4042-93a6-e8339132e20b/testpaths-credential-parameter-is-it-ever-used?forum=winserverpowershell). You may be able to "fake" it by using `invoke-command -computername <machinename> -credential $globalcred -scriptblock{test-path...}` to test the path locally (assumes you have remoting enabled) but it'll be slower and messier.

Comment: So you're saying that Test-Path doesn't work with the credential option.  I'll look into the invoke-command thing.  Thanks!

Comment: `Test-Path -Credential` *may* work in some cases. But likely not in the most common ones.

Comment: Do you know how I would get the computername for the remote location? It's a NAS that I have the path to.

Comment: See above for my update.

Comment: If it's a NAS, it's probably not running Windows, so `invoke-command` is a non-starter.

Comment: IMO a better solution to your problem would be to set the account to run under in the schedule task. If you have 4.0 you can do this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335134/how-to-test-writing-to-a-file-share-path-using-credential

Comment: @alroc-You're right, invoke-command was having issues with Remote Desktop not being installed on the NAS.

Comment: @Cole9350 - I am already running the backup and check scripts from my server as a scheduled task.  They are both backing up to the NAS and (trying to) check for the existance of the file backed up onto the NAS.  I will try the accepted answer to your link and see if I can use that to check for the file.  It's using similar credential usage as my backup script successfully uses and isn't using invoke-command, which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use what they are doing at the link to check for access so that I can check if a file exists or not.

Comment: @Michele If you are already using a scheduled task, you don't need credentials in the script. In task scheduler right click your task and select properties. Under General, Configure the "When running the task, use the following user account:" option

Comment: @Cole9350 the user account in Task Scheduler refers to accounts on the currently running server that Task Scheduler resides on, not the foreign NAS that I'm talking about, which has a different login.