# Access to default shares via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have an old script which at its core is enumerating the anonymous share on windows hosts:

```
NET USE \\hostname\ipc$ "" /u:"" 
NET USE
NET USE * /DELETE /y
```

I have tried a number of things but none of them works here's a few:

```
$username = ''
$password = ''
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,     $secstr
New-PSDrive -NAME X -PSprovider Filesystem -root "\\hostname\ipc$" -Credential $cred
```

OR:

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$updateprofile=$False
$user=""
$password=""
$net.MapNetworkDrive("L:", "\\hostname\ipc$", $updateprofile, $user, $password)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and I cannot find anything in the documentation.

PS
I know it's not good practice to have anon shares accessible, but is a legacy system with old stuff running which I have to maintain.
Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean by **none of them works**? Do you get an error? What if you try doing it without passing any authentication info? Wouldn't have thought using blank credentials would work.

Comment: You know you can use `net use` from powershell. Have a look here if you need to pass an authentication http://stackoverflow.com/a/21481027/381149

Comment: @arco444 by none of them works it means I get an authentication error. I have also tried without passing any auth info but complains about a missing username argument

Comment: @Kayasax yes but my point is not to use "net use" directly (sorry for the play on words!) as I shown in my first snippet of code . I am finding it odd that Powershell doesn't allow null sessions.

Comment: It appears that you can do this with WMI, see [http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/managing-file-shares-windows-powershell]

Comment: @Eris yes that enumerates all shares including the $IPC but cannot be used to actually "mount" the $IPC. I have found another way though which works very well.  Will auto-reply my answer below!